# Why i can't use "+" with type object Or What type of operators can be used with object

Tags: c#

What type of operators are available to use with object class?

```
public static void testing()
{
    object test = 10;
    object x = "a";
    object result = test + x;//compiler error
}
```

Why can't I use `+` with object type?

Comment: Because not every object can be added to something else. `Object` is the base class for all others, that means all classes share it's properties and methods.

Comment: you need to define the operator + for object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8edha89s.aspx) but i wouldnt recommend it for object

Comment: thanx.then what are the available operators to use with object type

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Check the list of C# operators where they are applicable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). You can create your own operator overloads for custom classes, but be very careful with that, as it may be hard to read and reason about for other programmers and yourself. Here's a list of overloadable operators, but some of them are constrained to specific arguments (not for example two objects) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx

Comment: @RehmanAhmadCh: look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx There are some methods but no operators. I guess that you want string concatenation in this case, therefore you can use `ToString` which every object has: `object result = test.ToString() + x.ToString()`. `String` supports the `+` operator by concatenating two strings to a new one.

Comment: You almost never need to use `object` in code directly. What are you trying to do? What should `new HttpWebRequest() + new RijndaelManaged()` return?

Comment: Joël Salamin and CodeCaster i was reading an article about difference in var,object and dynamic keyword,so i came to this situation as a newbie it was new thing for me that object is father  of all classes but it can use arthimatic operators

Comment: @SebastianL You can't overload `+` operator for `Object` + `Object` as you don't have the source code.

Comment: thanx All for ur reply,simply tell me have we some default opertors other than overloaded to use with object type.please reply even if u feel it silly question

Comment: There arent any operators for object, except "="

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default not every object supports operators like `+`, `-` or other ones. Imagine following class:

```
public class Weight
{
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

And following instances (to calculate the combined weight for example):

```
var w1 = new Weight { Value = 1 };
var w2 = new Weight { Value = 2 };
```

Doing following will result in a compiler error:

```
var result = w1 + w2;
```

The error will look like:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Weight' and 'Weight'

You have to overload the `+` operator to this:

```
public class Weight
{
    public int Value {get;set;}

    public static Weight operator +(Weight w1, Weight w2) 
    {
        return new Weight { Value = w1.Value + w2.Value };
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var result = w1 + w2;
Console.WriteLine(result.Value); //Writes: 3
```

Same goes for the `-` operator:

```
public static Weight operator -(Weight w1, Weight w2) 
{
    return new Weight { Value = w1.Value - w2.Value };
}
```

Further reading:

- [**C# Operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)
- [**Overloadable Operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Comment: thanx Abbas for ur reply,simply tell me have we some default opertors other than overloaded to use with object type.please reply even if u feel it silly question

Comment: Like I said, `object` doesn't support these operators by default, you have to overload them when creating a class.

Comment: Thanks again...it feels strange to me that object class don't have simple operators.only some methods and a constructor it has...its a  father of all other types

Comment: That is probably *the* reason why it is just so basic.

Comment: @RehmanAhmad: and that is the reason why it doesn't have a bunch of operators. How do you want to provide a meaningful operator for all possible child classes? The only one that comes to my mind is `o1 + o2` => `o1.ToString() + o2.ToString()`. But that is not a reason to provide an extra operator which can cause nasty bugs (consider f.e. that you forget that you haven't provided an operator in `Weight` above, you'd get objects implementation which is not desired).