# Where does string overload + operator for string concatenation?

Tags: c#, .net, string, operator-overloading

I recently wondered where [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.string.aspx) overloads the `+`-operator. The only methods i can see are [`==` and `!=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff986396(v=vs.110).aspx). Why can two strings be concatenated with + even if that operator is not overloaded? Is this just a *magic* compiler trick or am i missing something? If the former, why was string designed in that way?

This question was raised from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621726/why-i-cant-use-with-type-object-or-what-type-of-operators-can-be-used-with). It's difficult to explain someone that he cannot use `+` to concatenate two objects since `object` does not overload this operator if `string` does not care about overloading operators either.

Comment: Quite similar: [C# + operator calls string.concat function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617707/c-sharp-operator-calls-string-concat-function)

Comment: @SonerGönül: yes, now i've also found few questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator). I also wondered why i havent found a duplicate before i've asked this question.

Comment: Concerning the why: Keep in mind that the CLR supports many languages. Some might not want to follow C#'s dubious decision to use `+` for string concatenation with arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String doesn't overload `+` operator. It is the c# compiler which converts the call to `+` operator to `String.Concat` method.

Consider the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    string s1 = "";
    string s2 = "";

    bool b1 = s1 == s2;
    string s3 = s1 + s2;
}
```

Produces the IL

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       ""
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // s1
IL_0007:  ldstr       ""
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // s2
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     // s1
IL_000E:  ldloc.1     // s2
IL_000F:  call        System.String.op_Equality //Call to operator
IL_0014:  stloc.2     // b1
IL_0015:  ldloc.0     // s1
IL_0016:  ldloc.1     // s2
IL_0017:  call        System.String.Concat // No operator call, Directly calls Concat
IL_001C:  stloc.3     // s3
```

Spec calls this out here [7.7.4 Addition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), though it doesn't talks about call to `String.Concat`. We can assume it is implementation detail.

Comment: Can we have a definitive reference that proves this to be the case?

Comment: @spender Bear with me :) Working on it

Comment: Thanks. Is this also documented somewhere? Jon mentions also the reason for this implementation in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Read the tip section in this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat). I can't find official documentation. I'm trying to find it.

Answer (score 1):

This quote is from `C# 5.0 Specification 7.8.4 Addition operator`

**String concatenation:**

```
string operator +(string x, string y); 
string operator +(string x, object y); 
string operator +(object x, string y);
```

> These overloads of the binary `+` operator perform string
>   concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty
>   string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted
>   to its string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method
>   inherited from type object. If ToString returns null, an empty string
>   is substituted.

I'm not sure why is mentions about *overloading* though.. Since we don't see any operator overloads.

Comment: These are overloads at the C# level, just not at the CLR level.